# Wrong field label for lookups when using lightning-record-edit-form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

I'm having an issue when using Standard Lookups on lightning-record-edit-form. In the following example:

.html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form
            record-id={recordId}
            object-api-name={objectApiName}
            density="auto">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="RecordTypeId"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

.js:

```
import {LightningElement, wire, track, api} from 'lwc';

export default class Test5 extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;

}
```

The field label is not displayed properly:
[image]

The actual label of the field is Campaign Record Type, and it's displayed properly on the Page Layout.

As notes, we're using a generic version of the component in order to display various fields from multiple objects, so the workaround needs to be generic. Also, translations are needed in multiple languages, so this restricts the range of options.